# How to make ftp transfer of multiple files in directory (to remote) using find command output

Tags: bash, ftp

I've got to make a cron job of transfering over 100 backup *.tar.gz* files to ftp backup server. Stuck upon combining find command

```
 find /home/backup -mtime -1 -mmin +59 -type f -name "*.tar.gz*"
```

this part works fine, and script part:

```
#!/bin/sh
USERNAME="user"
PASSWORD="password"
SERVER="someip"
FILE="/home/backup"
DATE="`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S `"
BACKUPDIR="/backup/${DATE}/"

ftp -inv $SERVER <<EOF
user $USERNAME $PASSWORD
mkdir $BACKUPDIR
cd $BACKUPDIR
mput $FILE/*.tar.gz*
quit
EOF
```

for this

```
00 12 * * * find /home/backup -mtime -1 -mmin +59 -type f -name "*.tar.gz*" -exec /root/ftp.sh {} \;
```

doesn't work. No scp/ssh advice please) have to do it with ftp.

Comment: In the cronjob, you appear to use `find` to call the script once for each `tar.gz` file, yet inside the script you use `mput` and wildcards like you think the script is transferring lots of files...

Comment: Also, you don't set a PATH in your script, so you are kind of hoping that it will somehow know where to find `date`, and `ftp`.

Comment: Thank for your comment, Mark. Shall try to change script that way. No trouble with `date` or `ftp` noticed, probably uses system variables.

Comment: I suggest to replace `mput $FILE/*.tar.gz*` with `mput $1`.

Comment: Output looks like this
`/home/backup/20180402_122053_full.tar.gz.29
/home/backup/20180402_122053_full.tar.gz.94
/home/backup/20180402_122053_full.tar.gz.82
/home/backup/20180402_122053_full.tar.gz.3
/home/backup/20180402_122053_full.tar.gz.63`

Comment: Also I tried to replace FILE variable with find output `FILE="$(find /home/backup -mtime -1 -mmin +59 -type f -name "*.tar.gz*")"` but now it transfers only 1 file

Comment: Replacing `mput $FILE` with `mput $1` also didn't help, ftp response was 
`250 CWD successful. "/2018-04-02" is current directory.
(local-files) local: quit remote: quit
local: quit: No such file or directory`

Comment: I guess something about paths is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to make the crontab command smaller. Not that it shouldn't working your way, but it will be easier to understand what is happening.

```
00 12 * * * sh /root/ftpjob.sh
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh
username="user"
password="password"
server="someip"
sourcedir="/home/backup"
date="`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S `"
remotedir="/backup/${DATE}/"

find /home/backup -mtime -1 -mmin +59 -type f -name "*.tar.gz*" |
 while read filename ; do
    /bin/ftp -inv $server >> /tmp/ftpjob.log <<EOF
user $username $password
mkdir $remotedir
cd $remotedir
put $sourcedir/$filename
EOF
    echo "$date copied $filename" >> /tmp/ftpjob.log
done
```

This will work, as long as you are sure that your tar.gz filenames don't have spaces in them.

On the other hand, if you are able to do the ftp with an mput, there is no reason to do the find at all:

```
#!/bin/sh
username="user"
password="password"
server="someip"
sourcedir="/home/backup"
date="`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S `"
remotedir="/backup/${DATE}/"

/bin/ftp -inv $server >> /tmp/ftpjob.log <<EOF
user $username $password
mkdir $remotedir
cd $remotedir
mput $sourcedir/*.tar.gz.*
EOF
```

So, you would either use `find` to loop over the files, which is a good idea if there are multiple levels of directories where the tar.gz files are, or you would use `mput` in `ftp` if all the archives are always in the same directory.

Comment: I appreciate your answer Ljm, your suggestions were very helpful. Unfortunately I cannot get rid of `find` command for the task is to move today backups and ignore older ones. Sorry that didn't mention that before.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ljm Dullaart answer working script looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
USERNAME="user"
PASSWORD="password"
SERVER="someip"
DATE="`date +%Y-%m-%d `"
BACKUPDIR="/${DATE}/"

find . -mtime -1 -mmin +59 -type f -name "*.tar.gz*" -exec basename {} .tar.gz* \; |
  while read filename ; do
    /bin/ftp -inv $SERVER >> /tmp/ftp.log <<EOF
user $USERNAME $PASSWORD
mkdir $BACKUPDIR
cd $BACKUPDIR
put $filename
EOF
    echo "$date copied $filename" >> /tmp/ftp.log
done
```

yet can be done using a different loop:

```
#!/bin/sh
USERNAME="user"
PASSWORD="password"
SERVER="someip"
SOURCEDIR="/home/backup"
DATE="`date +%Y-%m-%d `"
BACKUPDIR="/${DATE}/"
cd /home/backup
for i in $(find /home/backup -mtime -1 -mmin +59 -type f -name "*.tar.gz*" -exec basename \{} . \;)
do
/bin/ftp -inv $SERVER >> /tmp/ftp.log <<EOF
user $USERNAME $PASSWORD
mkdir $BACKUPDIR
cd $BACKUPDIR
put $i
EOF
done
```

both will do for uploading backup files sorted by date via ftp.